# I have inconsistent attachment icon status when sending python email

Tags: python, smtplib

I am using [How to send email attachments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments)
as a basis to try and send an email with and without an attachment using python and have ended up with this code:

```
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate

def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=None):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)

    msg = MIMEMultipart('html')
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    for f in files or []:
        with open(f, "rb") as fil:
            part = MIMEApplication(fil.read(),Name=basename(f))
        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
        msg.attach(part)


    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.pobox.com', 465)
    server.login('<username>', '<password>')
    server.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    server.close()

send_mail("<username>",["<username>"],"subject","text",["D:\\Desktop\\Python Test\\Logfile.txt"]) # with attachment
#send_mail("<username>",["<username>"],"subject","Text") # without attachment
```

which appears to send an email with and without attachment depending on the last two lines of the code.

The problem is that with this line of code `msg = MIMEMultipart('html')` the email received does not show the paperclip attachment icon even if it `contains` an attachment in the email.  So, regardless of whether the email contains an attachment, there is no paperclip attachment icon.

If however, I change this to `msg = MIMEMultipart('')` I get a paperclip attachment icon on all emails even if they `dont` contain an attachment.

Does anyone know how I can fix this so that the paperclip attachment icon shows when there is an attachment and not when there isn't one?

Comment: It may help to specify a mimetype for the attachment - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63538330/5320906)

Comment: Tried adding code `mimetypes.guess_type(f)` as the attachment wont always be a specific type but I still get the same problem.